# Regex String out of Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to Regex specific strings out of the below:

```
{"thing":"Sample Stuff","more-stuff":"3.1.9.4"}
```

I'd like it to return:
    Sample Stuff

I would then count the instances of "Sample Stuff" (or whatever distinct value is in there). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(json, "\"thing\":\"[^\"].*", "$1")
```

Comment: it's still throwing an error in Redshift unfortunately

Comment: @user3597867 What is the exact error? Did you copy/paste my code?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift has a [`JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT` Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) that can return JSON elements, eg:

```
select json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"star"}}','f4', 'f6');

json_extract_path_text
---------------------- 
star
```